# List of job_state values for torque

Tags: bash, grep, pbs, torque

What are the possible values for job_state in Torque?

I looked in the related man pages have yet to find a complete list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Job state values from pbs_job.h:

T - transit
Q - queued
H - held
W - waiting (usually waiting for a file)
R - running
E - exiting
C - completed

Comment: I thought there were multiple types of holds. Do you know anything about this? Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple types of holds, but they are all one job state.